# Interlude on Traces (and another interlude on how bad of a writer Frohlich is)

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I'm trying to read through Frohlich's section of Algebraic Number Theory, but this guy really goes out of his way to make sure you don't understand anything.  Frohlich is probably the guy Serre is making fun of in his "How to Write Mathematics Badly" lecture, because he literally proves a theorem by citing two results, one of which is "By Euler's formulae" and the other is by "any old-fashioned textbook on algebra."

Anyway, you have an $n$-dimensional separable field extension $K \subseteq F$, and a corresponding inclusion of discrete valuation rings $A \subseteq B$, where $B$ is the integral closure of $A$ in $F$.  Also $e$ is the ramification index (and $f = n/e$), $P$ the unique prime ideal of $A$, and $\mathfrak B$ of $B$.  Also $\overline{B} = B/\mathfrak B$ and $\overline{A} = A/P$ The claim is that if $b \in B$: $$ Tr_{L/K}(b) + P = e Tr_{\overline{B}/\overline{A}}(b+ \mathfrak B)$$ Now $ B/PB = B/\mathfrak B^e$ is an $n$-dimensional algebra over $A/P$, so you can define a trace map $Tr$ there, and I think it's true that $Tr(b) = Tr_{L/K}(b) + P$, since you're just taking the matrix of the linear transformation and modding out.

Also, I think there is some isomorphism of $A/P$ modules: $B/\mathfrak B^e \cong B/\mathfrak B \oplus \mathfrak B/ \mathfrak B^2 \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathfrak B^{e-1} / \mathfrak B^e $.  I proved this before, but Frohlich claims that's obvious because of a "sequence of quotient spaces" (what does that even mean?).  Since each $\mathfrak B^i/ \mathfrak B^{i+1}$ is an $f$-dimensional vector space over $A/P$, you can define a trace map $Tr_i$ there as well.  We then see the following shenanigans: $$ Tr(b) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{e-1} Tr_i(b) $$ which I assume is calculated by finding an appropriate matrix to represent the multiplication map for $B/\mathfrak B^e$ as some block diagonal sum of other matrices.  I blame Frohlich for crushing my self esteem and rendering me unable to deduce the details of this detail-less construction on my own.  The proof ends by noting that because $\mathfrak B^i/ \mathfrak B^{i+1} \cong B/ \mathfrak B$ as $A/P$ modules, that $Tr_i = Tr_{\overline{B}/ \overline{A}}$.

99% of the time, I totally agree with the philosophy that the most you should get on something you're stuck on is a cryptic hint, and if you ask for more then you're an entitled snot who needs to sit down and figure it all out on your own.  But that's what I've been doing for the 20 pages I've read of this book so far (I've been trying to read this book for two months and that's as far as I've gotten, sad I know), and I'm just begging someone to please explain *everything* about this problem so I can stop banging my head against this table.  I will never ask for help again for as long as I live.

Comment: This question would be much better without the rant.

Comment: This question would be a lot better without the first and last paragraphs.

Comment: Friend, don't worry. We all have those theorems that, for some reason or other, just elude us. Settle this one with yourself, be happy, and continue learning :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not precisely sure what your questions are.

Note that $\text{Tr}_{L/K}(b)=\text{Tr}_{B/A}(b)$ by definition. But, this is is just the trace of the $A$-linear map $m_b:B\to B$ (where $m_b$ is multiplication by $b$). This induces a map, by tensor product

$$m_b\otimes\text{id}:B\otimes_A A/P\to B\otimes_A A/P$$

But,

$$B\otimes_A A/P=B/PB=B/\mathfrak{P}^e$$

As you stated, $B/\mathfrak{P}^e\cong (B/\mathfrak{P})^e$ as $A/P$-vector spaces. The filtration he's talking about is

$$\mathfrak{P}\supseteq\mathfrak{P}^2\supseteq\cdots\supseteq\mathfrak{P}^e$$

It's obvious then that $\dim_{A/P}B/\mathfrak{P}^e$ is

$$\sum_{i=1}^{e-1}\dim_{A/P}\mathfrak{P}^i/\mathfrak{P}^{i+1}$$

But, $\mathfrak{P}^i/\mathfrak{P}^{i+1}\cong B/\mathfrak{P}$ as an $A/P$ vector space. Indeed, letting $\pi$ be a uniformizer of $\mathfrak{P}$ the isomorphism is just the one induced from the map $B\to (\pi^i)/(\pi^{i+1})$ given by multiplication by $\pi^i$ (the kernel is obviously $(\pi)$).

I leave it to you to then check that under the isomorphism $B\otimes_A A/P\cong B/\mathfrak{P}^e\cong (B/\mathfrak{P})^e$ the map $m_b\otimes \text{id}$ travels to multiplication by $b+\mathfrak{P}$ on each entry (just do this explicitly). Thus, you see that

$$\text{Tr}_{L/K}(b)+P=\text{Tr}_{B/A}(b)+P=\text{Tr}_{(B/\mathfrak{P}^e)/(A/P)}(m_b\otimes\text{id})=e\text{Tr}_{\overline{B}/\overline{A}}(b+\mathfrak{P})$$

as desired.

It's also good to note that this didn't require $A$ to be a DVR, but just a Dedekind domain. The only trickier part is to verify that $B/\mathfrak{P}^e$ is isomorphic to $(B/\mathfrak{P})^e$ as $A/P$-modules (via the natural map). One just does this locally, and since we're in a Dedekind domain this reduces to the DVR case as above.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  What exactly is the isomorphism $B/ \mathfrak P^e \rightarrow (B/ \mathfrak P)^e$?  I'm having trouble defining it explicitly to show that the reinterpretation of $m_b$ is multiplication by $b + \mathfrak P$.